# XJC - Generate xml using Xpath

Tags: java, xml, xjc

After converting XSD to java objects using XJC , I would like to generate an xml file giving xpath and value to the xpath.

Examples.

Say I'm giving xpath and the value as

```
customer/name = XXXXX_VALUE
```

It should assign internally to the generated objects ... `CustomerType.setName()` ..

An XML also should generate as expected following the Xpath rule.

I know in Castor we can do this using ClassDescripor and FieldDescriptor. But I would like to know how to do this using XJC

Comment: Why do you expect that someone else has written one of these that you can't find with google?

Comment: @bmargulies : That is Java :)

Answer (score 0):

JXPath can be used to navigate javabeans via something similar to xpaths. 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/

Specifically, when you supply a factory you can create objects. There are several situations that are not supported nativly, but with a little bit of thought you can implement your own extension of createPathAndSetValue that can deal with your specific predicate logic.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/users-guide.html#Creating_Objects